# Does the functor of taking invariants commute with tensor products?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group acting on a commutative ring $R$, inducing an action on each $R$-module. For any $R$-module $M$, let $M^G$ denote the collection of elements of $M$ invariant under the $G$-action. Then, $M^G$ is an $R^G$-module.

Here is my question. Do we have:

$$  (M\otimes_RN)^G=M^G\otimes_{R^G}N^G $$

for $R$-modules $M$ and $N$?

At least does it hold if $M$ and $N$ are projective? Clearly, this holds when they are free modules.

Are there conditions on the group $G$ that could create this situation? For example, $G$ could be a finite group or an abelian group or a linear reductive group... etc etc

Or perhaps, there could be conditions on the ring $R$ for which we get the above equality?

Comment: When you say $G$ acts on $R$, do you just mean on the underlying additive group, or what?

Comment: Hi, I meant to say that each $g\in G$ gives a ring automorphism of $R$.

Comment: How does an action of $G$ on $R$ induce an action on an $R$-module?

Comment: If $g:R\longrightarrow R$ is a morphism of rings, for an $R$-module $M$, we have $g:M\cong M\otimes_RR\overset{1\otimes g}{\longrightarrow}M\otimes_RR\cong M$. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no meaning to "$G$ is a group acting on a commutative ring $R$, inducing an action on each $R$-module".  I advise you to read about "$G$-linearizations" in a reference such as "Geometric Invariant Theory", Mumford, Fogarty, Kirwan.  For an action of $G$ on $R$, there are some $R$-modules that will admit no compatible $G$-action, e.g., if the support of the module is not a $G$-invariant subset of $\text{Spec}(R)$.  On the other hand, modules may admit many different compatible $G$-actions.

Comment: @Suresh.  For an $R$-module homomorphism $\phi:N\to N$, there is an induced $R$-module homomorphism $1\otimes \phi:M\otimes_R N \to M\otimes_R N$.  However, the ring automorphism induced by $g$ is not an $R$-module homomorphism of $R$.

Comment: Suresh, if $g$ acts as a ring automorphism and thus preserves $1 \in R$, then the composite you described in your last comment is the identity on $M$.

Comment: Simple example: if $S$ is a ring, then $C_2$ acts on the ring $S\times S$ by swapping the two factors. $M=S\times\{0\}$ is an $S\times S$-module, but I think it's fairly clear that there's no action of $C_2$ on it that is "induced" in any reasonable way by the action on $S\times S$.

Comment: There are a lot of comments about confusions in the way the question is phrased, but I suspect the answer is "no" however the ambiguities are resolved. Let $R =\mathbb{C}$ with the trivial action of $G=C_2$. Let $M$ and $N$ be $\mathbb{C}$ with $G$ acting by $-1$. Then $M^G=N^G=0$ but $(M \otimes_R N)^G = M \otimes_R N$.